# Как из формы, редактировать dataGridView данные текстового файла, из которого и выводятся dataGridView строки в форму?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа, которая читая данные из текстового файла "данные.cfg" , выводит их в строки dataGridvView.
Допустим в файле "данные.cfg" есть: аккуант|пароль|. В dataGridView выводится:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           int num2;
           ManagementObjectCollection instances = new ManagementClass("win32_processor").GetInstances();           
           string[] strArray = File.ReadAllLines("данные.cfg", Encoding.UTF8);            
           Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);
           for (num2 = -0; num2 < strArray.Length; num2++)
               {
                    if (strArray[num2][0] != '#')
                    {
                       string[] strArray2 = strArray[num2].Split(new char[] { '|' });                       
                       this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                       this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = strArray2[0];
                       this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = strArray2[1];
                       string аккуант = strArray2[0];
                       string пароль = strArray2[1];
                    }
               }
        }
```

Как сделать чтоб при выделении одной или более строки в форме а после, при нажатии определенной клавиши, уже в файле "данные.cfg", перед аккуант|пароль|(а именно перед словом аккуант) ставился/сохранялся символ #

Comment: Заведите скрытую колонку в DGV с данными типа bool. И изменяйте ее состояние. При загрузке и сохранении учитывайте ее значение. true - есть #, false - нет.

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8` можно кстати не указывать, это значение по умолчанию. Так же, не используйте кириллицу в названиях переменных, оставьте эту привелегию 1С разработчикам. Вы же знаете слова `account` и `password`.

Comment: это пример просто. На фаил называется не "данные.cfg" а иначе и данные в нем тоже не по рускки указаны, это я для примера